# Как показать только 5 пользователей, которые имеют самый высокий рейтинг среди всех комментариев используя связку двух таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Существуют две таблицы, которые связаны между собой внешним ключом.

Нужно показать 5 пользователей, которые имеют самый высокий рейтинг среди всех комментариев.

*Схема БД:*

[image: Схема БД]

Использую СУБД - `MYSQL`, хочу выполнить обычный `SQL` запрос, как я понимаю, с использованием `LEFT JOIN`, но в связке `JOIN` с `MAX` и `LIMIT` появляются трудности.

Comment: подскажите, какая у вас  СУБД какая?

Comment: СУБД?, голые sql-запросы или какой-то фреймворк? Добавьте всё это, чтобы Вам можно было корректно ответить.

Comment: `select * from (select * from table order by raiting) limit 5` - предположительно как то так

Comment: Viktorov, данный запрос не сработает,ведь мне,как я понимаю нужно использовать джойн?:(

Comment: Собственно из вашего вопроса не понятно, с чем именно у вас проблема. Прочитайте [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и добавьте примеры, ваши попытки решения и что не устраивает

Comment: к примеру пишу такой запрос, но он не правильный: SELECT *
FROM user LEFT JOIN comment
ON user.id = comment.id WHERE comment.user_id =  (SELECT MAX(rating) FROM comment) LIMIT 5

Comment: `select * from (SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN comment ON user.id = comment.id order by comment.raiting) limit 5` - попробуйте что-то такое

Comment: Выдало ошибку #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias . И где тут  выборка по максимуму?:(

Comment: Как связать  LEFT JOIN с  MAX??

Comment: @VladimirMarakhovskii идея была в том, чтобы упорядочить по максимуму и взять первые 5 строк после сортировки. Попробуйте так `SELECT * FROM user JOIN comment ON user.id = comment.id order by comment.raiting desc limit 5`. И вам не нужен `left`

Comment: что то ві мне советуете не то:((#1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'comment.raiting' в 'order clause'

Comment: Прочитайте ошибку, исправьте мою опечатку. Попробуйте попытаться понять происходящее, а не бездумно копировать

Comment: Ну смотрите, есть результат с таким запросом: select * from  user AS u LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON u.id = c.id  ORDER BY c.rating DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: Не понял так почему нельзя указывать MAX в запросе :((

Comment: вам не нужен left join. хватит просто join. Вместо выбора максимального мой запрос как бы говорит "соединить 2 таблицы, отсортировать в порядке убывания рейтинга и взять первые 5 строк".

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки,надеюсь правильно написал:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не самый красивый и быстрый вариант конечно, но должен отработать

```
select * from 
(
  select 
    u.*,
    (select max(rating) from comment c where c.user_id = u.id) as rating
  from 
    user u
) ret
where rating is not null
order by rating desc
limit 5;
```

Можете использовать как отправную точку и попробовать избавиться от вложенных запросов. 
Работающий пример можно глянуть [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb24de/14);

Comment: tym32167, Спасибо и Вам:)

Comment: @VladimirMarakhovskii если ответ вам помог, галочка слева от ответа

Comment: Вопрос решен.Спасибо и тому кто поставил минус к моему вопросу,надеюсь он выплеснул свою злобу:)

Comment: Я написал свой рабочий из подсказок выше, Ваш думаю по-лучше будет, тоже рабочий,еще раз благодарю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, удачи в изучении SQL :)